# How to change the size of text in JTextbox dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I have following code which is running fine, but I want to know if there is any method which can change the font size to fill maximum area in JTextBox. When I am running to code on three different theme it is giving me different results.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.Component;
public class NewLoginBox extends JDialog {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField userID;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            NewLoginBox dialog = new NewLoginBox();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public NewLoginBox() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 350, 220);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Sign In", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        {
            JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
            contentPanel.add(titlePanel);
            titlePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(titlePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            {
                JLabel lblPleaseEnterYour = new JLabel("Welcome to Application. Please Sign In ");
                lblPleaseEnterYour.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                lblPleaseEnterYour.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
                lblPleaseEnterYour.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                titlePanel.add(lblPleaseEnterYour);
                titlePanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
            }
        }
        {
            JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();
            contentPanel.add(formPanel);
            formPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
            {
                JLabel lblUserId = new JLabel("User ID");
                formPanel.add(lblUserId);
            }
            {
                userID = new JTextField("", 15);
                formPanel.add(userID);
                userID.setColumns(10);
            }
            {
                JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
                formPanel.add(lblPassword);
            }
            {
                passwordField = new JPasswordField();
                formPanel.add(passwordField);
            }
        }
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
            {
                JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
                buttonPane.add(btnHelp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Nimbus Look and feel] - which is have best look and feel.

[image: Window Look and feel]

[image: Swing Look and feel]

Now what I want that the size of Jtextbox should be dynamically change according to the text inside it. so that we can have consistent look and feel.
Thanks
Ashish Tyagi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't use GridLayout for your formPanel. Instead use GridBagLayout.
- Or consider using a 3rd party layout such as [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).
- Don't set the bounds of your GUI's. Instead let the layout managers do that for you.
- Don't forget to call `pack()` on your top level windows after filling them with components and before displaying them.

For example,

NewLoginBox.java:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.Component;

public class NewLoginBox extends JDialog {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField userID;
   private JPasswordField passwordField;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         NewLoginBox dialog = new NewLoginBox();
         dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         dialog.pack();
         dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         dialog.setVisible(true);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public NewLoginBox() {
      //setBounds(100, 100, 350, 220);
      // getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      TitledBorder titledBorder = new TitledBorder(null, "Sign In",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null);
      int ebGap = 10;
      EmptyBorder emptyBorder = new EmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap);
      Border compoundBorder = new CompoundBorder(titledBorder, emptyBorder);
      contentPanel.setBorder(compoundBorder );
      getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
      contentPanel.add(titlePanel);
      titlePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(titlePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      JLabel lblPleaseEnterYour = new JLabel(
            "Welcome to Application. Please Sign In ");
      lblPleaseEnterYour.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      lblPleaseEnterYour.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
      lblPleaseEnterYour.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
      titlePanel.add(lblPleaseEnterYour);
      titlePanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));

      JPanel formPanel = new JPanel();
      contentPanel.add(formPanel);

      // formPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
      ebGap = 7;
      formPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));
      formPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      JLabel lblUserId = new JLabel("User ID");
      addWithGbc(formPanel, lblUserId, 0, 0);
      userID = new JTextField("", 15);
      addWithGbc(formPanel, userID, 1, 0);
      userID.setColumns(10);
      JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
      addWithGbc(formPanel, lblPassword, 0, 1);
      passwordField = new JPasswordField();
      addWithGbc(formPanel, passwordField, 1, 1);
      JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
      buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
      getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
      okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
      buttonPane.add(okButton);
      getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
      JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
      cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
      buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
      JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
      buttonPane.add(btnHelp);
   }

   private void addWithGbc(Container container, JComponent component, int x,
         int y) {
      int hGap = 5;

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      if (x % 2 == 0) {
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
         gbc.insets = new Insets(hGap, 0, hGap, 20); // magic number!
         gbc.weightx = 1.0;
         gbc.weighty = 1.0;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      } else {
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
         gbc.insets = new Insets(hGap, 0, hGap, 0);
         gbc.weightx = 1.0;
         gbc.weighty = 0.0;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      }
      container.add(component, gbc);
   }
}
```

Comment: As always, I can agree to your suggestions :-) +1 for that

Comment: @Hovercraft I have one more thing about the same questions, so when I am adding the component as mentioned in my code(offcourse with gridbaglayout) they are properly align and appearing but when I am adding them through the method addWithGbc () only Username is visible and other component is not appearing. Is there anything I am doing not write.